# Euler product formula for prime ideals

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, infinite-product, zeta-functions

I would like to show that

> The product $\prod\limits_{\mathfrak p} (1 - N(\mathfrak p)^{-s})$ converges absolutely iff the series $\sum\limits_{\mathfrak p} N(\mathfrak p)^{-s}$ converges absolutely, where $\mathfrak p$ runs through the prime ideals of a number field $K$ and $s>1$.

I know that the product $\prod_{n \geq 1} (1 + x_n)$ with $|x_n| < 1$ converges absolutely [iff](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Infinite_product) the series $\sum_{n \geq 1} x_n$ converges absolutely.
We have 
$$-\sum\limits_{\mathfrak p} N(\mathfrak p)^{-s} = 
-\sum\limits_{p} \sum\limits_{\mathfrak p \mid p} N(\mathfrak p)^{-s} = 
\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n, \qquad
a_p := \sum\limits_{\mathfrak p \mid p} -N(\mathfrak p)^{-s}, a_n=0 \text{ if $n$ is not prime}$$
so applying the above theorem yields the product
$$\prod_{n \geq 1} (1 + a_n) = 
\prod_{p} \left(1 - \sum\limits_{\mathfrak p \mid p} N(\mathfrak p)^{-s}\right)$$

I don't see how this can be equal to $$\prod\limits_{\mathfrak p} (1 - N(\mathfrak p)^{-s})$$
because my previous product will "miss" the "double" factors like $N(\mathfrak p)N(\mathfrak p')$.

Thank you!

Comment: Any reference of the formula? This is different from the Euler's product formula I know. Thanks!

Comment: @S. Y : We have $\prod_{\mathfrak p} (1-N(\mathfrak p)^{-s})^{-1} = \sum_I N(I)^{-s}$ (Neukirch ANT p. 457), but the results above equivalence of convergences come from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159416).

Comment: Make a bijection $n \leftrightarrow \mathfrak{p}$ (as the set of prime ideals is countably infinite). It follows that the product $\prod_{\mathfrak{p}} (1 + x_{\mathfrak{p}})$ with $|x_{\mathfrak{p}}| < 1$ converges absolutely iff the series $\sum_{\mathfrak{p}} x_{\mathfrak{p}}$ converges absolutely. Now set $x_{\mathfrak{p}} = -N(\mathfrak{p})^{-s}$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319431/

Comment: @PeterHumphries : thank you for your comment! So if I understand well, _absolute_ convergence is important here, because otherwise the choice of a bijection $n \leftrightarrow \mathfrak p$ would have an influence on the (conditional) convergence. Am I right?

Comment: @PeterHumphries : By the way, you could provide this as an answer. I would enjoy accepting it, then :-)